# Jenkins Powershell start-process starts the proccess and immediately closes it

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I am using Jenkins with Powershell Plugin to start a simple script on Nodes.
When I build the Job with the Powershell plugin the script opens the Notepad and immediately closes it.
Example:

```
start-process notepad.exe
```

All it does is it opens the Notepad and immediately closes it.
Please does anyone know where the issue could be ?

Comment: How is the node running? When it runs as a service it will have issues launching interactive processes. Do you succeed launching console processes (e. g. "cmd.exe")?

Comment: @zett42 Node is running through command prompt I started with with Admin account.
Yes when I do it through cmd.exe notepad starts correctly and is not closed immediately.

Comment: Is the Jenkins job still running when notepad terminates? It could be that Jenkins kills all child processes when the job ends.

Comment: @zett42 nope the job is not running after that

Comment: Do you actually intend to keep the process running after the job has finished?